# Fatal error: Cannot instantiate non-existent class: directoryiterator

Tags: php

Need some help with this error. Fresh wordpress 2.9 install...

Fatal error: Cannot instantiate non-existent class: directoryiterator in /home1/test/public_html/test2/wp-content/themes/mytheme/functions.php on line 471

```
function get_dirs($path = '.') {
$dirs = array();
foreach (new DirectoryIterator($path) as $file) {   //THIS IS LINE 471
    if ($file->isDir() && !$file->isDot()) {
        $dirs[] = $file->getFilename();
    }
}

return $dirs;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DirectoryIterator` class is part of the [Standard PHP Library (SPL)](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php), which is [installed by default](http://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.installation.php) in PHP 5. Maybe you are using PHP 4?

**EDIT**

To get information on your PHP installation, use [phpinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php). Create a .php file with this single line and open it in your browser:

```
<?php phpinfo() ?>
```

Comment: I suppose that could be the culprit. Its on a shared server installation of wordpress. How can I query the PHP version via script?

Comment: Assuming its version 4, can I add the class in a utility file perhaps?

Comment: Hmm, I think you will need a custom implementation then. *At your own risk*, this is what google found for example: http://www.weberdev.com/get_example-4180.html

Comment: or, inform at your shared host if they also support php 5, if they do switch your domain to that version.

Comment: I did the phpinfo() file and it reports...

PHP Version 4.4.9

So I suppose I need to do a check for the existence of the class and if its not that, do a require on the script that I'll have to create to sub...

Comment: Googling "DirectoryIterator for php4" will get you some functions which mirror the SPL function. 
Check the output of PHP_VER and if it is 4 then include one of those functions.